# GIS Layer of USA State Court Jurisdiction Boundaries

Tags: data, united-states

Does anyone know of a national layer?

I am looking for all courts (district, circuit, municipal, Superior, etc.) depending on the terminology used for the state for the USA.

Based on the answers provided and research I've done I don't believe this is available.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few clicks deeper I found this...
[text files will work](http://www.fedstats.gov/qf/download_data.html)
and here is the shape file
[judicial_districts.shp](http://tinyurl.com/27o9xyz)

Comment: Links are broken

Answer (score 1):

If you mean state district courts, like these:

- http://www.mncourts.gov/?page=238
- http://www.sconet.state.oh.us/JudSystem/districtCourts/

it seems like many of them use county boundaries, so it'd be something you could create from a national county layer if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [a shapefile of the 94 US District Court jurisdictions](https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/us-district-court-jurisdictions) on the "Homeland Infrastructure Foundation-Level Data (HIFLD)" site.

I haven't found a GIS map of the Federal circuits, but there's an image of one on the [United States courts of appeals Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_courts_of_appeals), as well as [a text listing of the districts which each circuit comprises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_courts_of_appeals#Circuit_composition) (It seems as though all districts in any state are in the same circuit, so it would be easier to have a list of states, but I haven't seen a list in that format.)